# What is the difference between using Stream.ofNullable() and stream()?

Tags: java, java-stream

While working with Streams in `Java 11`, I noticed the following situation. I'm trying to use the Stream API in two different ways on a non-null list.

First way:

```
Collection<Object> categoryIds = List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L);

List<String> nullable = Stream.ofNullable(categoryIds)
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Second way:

```
Collection<Object> categoryIds = List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L);

List<String> nullable = categoryIds.stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The two ways I tried lead to two different results. The resulting list of the first way is a string containing a single element. This string is: `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"` The second way gives the desired and expected results. Returns a result list with 4 elements: `"1", "2", "3", "4"`.

Is this behavior expected? Or is it a problem?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`Stream.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T))? When the list is not null, it's basically the same as `Stream.of`.

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. One gives you a stream from a single nullable element, the other from an object that already has a `stream()` method, typically a collection. So *you would expect* a stream of one in the first case and a stream of > 1 in the second. Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: it does seem like a strange function, since the resulting stream can only have 0 or 1 elements. Why would I use it over an `Option`?

Comment: @julaine assuming `Optional` (not `Option`): sometimes you need a `Stream` (e.g. test/call a method that has such a parameter; or to use some method of `Stream` [`collect()`, `toList()`, ...]) -- sure, it is *optional*, we could also do `Optional.ofNullable(..).stream()`

Comment: @user85421 Yes, I meant `Optional`. Thanks. Seems like a rare usecase with a short and obvious workaround, so it seems weird to define an additional stdlib-function for it. But whatever, it's Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stream.ofNullable](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) you are creating a `Stream` object with single element or empty Stream for null object

> Returns a sequential Stream containing a single element, , if non-null, otherwise returns an empty Stream.

If you want to get the same output using `Stream.ofNullable` you need to flatten the list using `flatMap`

```
List<String> nullable = Stream.ofNullable(categoryIds)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Collection.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) - it creates the stream object with collection elements in sequential order

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.

And the `Collection.stream` is equivalent to [stream.of(T... values)](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) method

```
 List<String> nullable = Stream.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L) // or categoryIds.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

`Stream.ofNullable(obj)` is just equivalent of `obj == null ? Stream.empty() : Stream.of(obj)`.

So yes, it is expected behaviour.
what happened is you created a stream from one element which was a list (So you had a `Stream<List<Integer>>` instead of `Stream<Integer>`). Next, you just stringified a whole list (having one-element `Stream<String>`) and ended up with a one-element string list after `.collect()`.

So if you want to have a stream of elements from the list, you need to flatten it first. For example like this:

```java
Stream
   .ofNullable(categoryIds)
   .flatMap(Collection::stream)
   .map(Object::toString)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
   ;
```

On the other hand, if you used a `Stream.of(categoryIds)` or `categoryIds.stream()` with a null `categoryIds` object, you would end up with `NullPointerException` and thats where `Stream.ofNullable` comes in handy.

Comment: +1 for showing how to get the stream that OP expects/wants using the provided API. But nobody can tell me this is more readable than a bit of very simple procedural code to handle a null.

Comment: Nobody said that this is more readable. :) Imho, it's a matter of getting used to it. Some prefer this, others that. The API method exists, so you need to know what is its expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `Stream.ofNullable(categoryIds)` and `categoryIds.stream()` behave differently is because `Stream.ofNullable(T t)` expects a single object that will be treated as an element of the stream, in your case the collection `categoryIds` (see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T))). Even though this collection contains several elements, the method won't stream them, instead, it will create a stream of `Collection<Object>` where the only element is `categoryIds`. This also explains why your first stream returns a single `String` element, because the only element in your stream (`categoryIds`) is mapped to the value returned from the invocation of its `toString()` method.

On the other hand, the `stream()` method of the `Collection` interface has a very different meaning (see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--)), as the `Collection` is treated as the source of the stream. This means that the stream will iterate through the elements of `categoryIds`, and not treat the `Collection` as an element of the stream.

> Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.

The difference appears even more obvious when you notice how the role of `categoryIds` changes in the two writings. In fact, in the first case `categoryIds` is passed as a parameter to the stream, therefore you're creating a stream of collections. While in the second case, the method is invoked **from** `categoryIds`, creating a stream with its elements.

Finally, `Stream.ofNullable` is to be used in those instances where we need to create a stream from a single element, but we cannot admit null values (or better value) in our stream. It is simply a check that guarantees non null elements. Conversely, The method `stream()` allows null elements too.

As others have already mentioned, if you have a collection as an element of your stream, and you want to replace it with its elements, you need to invoke the [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operation.

```
Collection<Object> categoryIds = List.of(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L);

List<String> nullable = Stream.ofNullable(categoryIds)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .map(Object::toString)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```